# Rails: output deprecation warnings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, upgrade, deprecation-warning

What kind of deprecation warnings should we expect from Rails?

About to upgrade from Rails 4.1 -> 4.2 and I'm looking in the terminal and the `development.log` for deprecation warnings and not seeing any. Either I'm looking in the wrong places...or I don't have any.

However, I do have an instance of `File.exists?` in this codebase and I know that is (was?) deprecated in favor of `File.exist?`. Will Rails flag this for me *somewhere*, as some other frameworks do, or do I need to uncover/discover these issues myself?

Answer (score 3):

Rails will log deprecations - how this is done is controlled by the `config.active_support.deprecation` setting (`:log`, `:stderr`, `:raise`, `:silence` or `:notify`)

`File.exist?` is a ruby method though and so is not affected by this setting. Ruby will emit a warning if you use this method, although you will need to run ruby with warnings enabled to see them.